# Does OpenMapTiles support offline usage?

Tags: openmaptiles

I'm looking to download the following tileset (v3.11 released in 2020) from https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/tileset/osm/asia/malaysia-singapore-brunei/

There is a preview provided of how the full tileset looks like. Could I just check if the level of detail shown in the preview will be the same if these vector tiles are used in an offline setting? Or will the quality be compromised if used offline (no Internet). Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

There are different opportunities for running your own server locally for presenting any desired tileset.

As given on linked page you can freely download either tileset for evaluation purposes. Next, you can set up [docker](https://www.docker.com/) on your local computer to run any downloaded tileset for you. Related instructions for doing so are provided on either of the following sites:

- https://openmaptiles.com/server/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/klokantech/tileserver-gl/